# Fade splash screen after delay on iOS 7 with PhoneGap 3.2

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, phonegap-plugins

PhoneGap 2.5 permitted users to fade out the splash screen after a delay (http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/guide_project-settings_ios_index.md.html), but the functionality seems no longer documented in PhoneGap 3.2. If the functionality was removed, is there another way of accomplishing this within PhoneGap, or do we need to programmatically implement this by adding the Splash Screen plugin ourselves?

We already tried adding `<preference name="fade-splash-screen-duration" value="5" />`
to the `config.xml` file under the project folder, but it had no effect.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding this in the config.xml

```
<preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="false" />
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="true" />
<preference name="fade-splash-screen-duration" value="5" />
```

and this in the onDeviceReady();

```
setTimeout(function() {
     navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I tried this using Phonegap 3.1 on iOS and it didn't work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Kevin's example works, but the only preference actually required is:

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```